# Rename Xbox tag to Xbox Original to avoid confusion?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think we should change the `xbox` tag to `xbox-original` to avoid confusion between what used to be called the xbox one and what is now called the xbox one.

Comment: I doubt we'll have enough [tag:xbox-og] questions to warrent the tag, honestly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this is necessary.

1. The original Xbox is called the Xbox. That is what it is.
2. People visiting this site, should at least have enough domain-specific knowledge to understand that the two systems are different.

Comment: I also just created a tag for [`xbox-one`](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/xbox-one/info) 15 minutes before this post.

Comment: That being said and thought I agree with your idea that people should have domain-specific knowledge, but I also think it would be nice if we rename the the current tag, and add a new xbox tag after that. This way people will be able to ask question specifically about any version of xbox or about xbox development in general.

Comment: maybe questions asking about MS policy fall in the second category.

Comment: I don't really see a need to rename the tag, and I especially don't see a need to have both 'xbox' (to cover "Xbox in general") and 'xbox-original' (or whatever). I can't think of good, on-topic questions that would be made more searchable by the existence of such a tag.